# NSAttributedString specify range?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Is it possible to specify a range when using `-[NSAttributedString initWithString:attributes:]`?

I know I can do it with `NSMutableAttributedString`, but I wanted to be more efficient by using `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Oh, 27 more characters: remember to profile before worrying about efficiency.